# FileObserver for Chromebook Downloads directory is never notified

Tags: android, chromebook, fileobserver

I have an android app running on Chromebooks. I'm using FileObserver to watch a few common directories and notify changes. This is successful in all locations except the downloads directory on my chromebook.

Downloads directory on this specific chromebook is `/storage/MyFiles/Downloads`. Do chrombook downloads directories have special protections? (are we not allowed to monitor there?)

If this is a security issue or otherwise intentional and you have a source, please share it

This is how the device filesystem looks in AS:

[image: Device Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: That is a strange path. Are the paths like that for `a few common directories`?

Comment: @blackapps I've added a screenshot

Comment: You did not tell which `few common directories` you are observing. Moreover there is a `/sdcard/Download` directory. There will be a `/storage/emulated/0/Download` directory too.

Comment: Pretty stange that you can have a `/storage/MyFiles` directory. You said `/sdcard/MyFiles`.

Comment: No, nothing in emulated works on this device. This whole device has a strange implementation. I wanted to make sure that viewing downloads isnt completely banned in chromebooks